# Community and Blog page using Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

Amazed with the overall feature of Oracle Apex 4.1 and its increasing popularity in replacing Oracle Forms. I am currently working on a idea to implement an internal oracle community page with technical Forums (say like oracle forums, ask tom etc) along with a blog page. Can this be done using Oracle Apex? Can any one suggest a any sample public application/web site having the same features to have a look and feel.

Cheers,
Arun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, pretty much any web site could be written with Oracle Apex; a blog or forum would be achievable. Personally, I'd rather use an off-the-shelf platform (e.g. wordpress for blogging), but if you need it integrated with your existing Apex site then it probably makes sense.

See an example here: http://www.apexblogs.info

Ask Tom also uses apex: http://asktom.oracle.com

There used to be sample applications on [Oracle's web site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/packaged-apps-090453.html), but it appears they've been removed: *"The Application Express team is developing a number of new, more advanced applications. These new applications are planned to be available as part of the Oracle Database Cloud Service."*

Comment: Wow...nice to see apexblogs.info. How can I insert a comment box at end of the blog post. And the themes are these come along with the package?

Comment: Apex comes with a number of themes. If you want one like apexblogs you'd need to build it yourself - the Apex theme editor is not hard to use if you know HTML and CSS.

Comment: A comment box is just a text field, and on page submit you'd insert the comment into a table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You might jump start your efforts by looking at Apex blogging applications created by others

For example:

http://www.apexninjas.com/blog/2011/12/the-apexninjas-blog-platform-v2-0-is-released/
http://dbswh.webhop.net/dbswh/f?p=BLOG:READ:0::::ARTICLE:1953900346140572